# Embed multiple videos into one embeded object

Tags: html, embed, moodle, src, quicktime

I'm working with Moodle to embed videos for an online class and I'm having trouble with the formats. I want to include close captions on the video and Apple Compressor does not seem to save captions to MP4 files. Therefore, I've started using .mov files instead of MP4s. Unfortunately, some students seem to have trouble viewing the .mov files. I was wondering if it would be possible to embed the .mov files and have the quicktime player default to the .mp4 if the .mov file didn't work.

I know this is possible with HTML5 videos, but unfortunately the current faculty wants to keep using the embedded QuickTime player. Here's what I have so far:

Is it possible to include two srcs somehow?

Thanks so much!

Comment: <embed src="wrightwithcaptions.mov" type="video/mp4" autostart="false" height="430" width="540" />

Can I put in a second src somehow?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `type="video/quicktime"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to solve the problem with javascript. With this code, you can provide a link to change the source link to mp4:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fallback_to_mp4(video_id) {
        var video = document.getElementById(video_id);
        var mov_url = video.GetURL();
        var newsrc = mov_url.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mp4";
        video.SetURL(newsrc);
    }
</script>

<embed src="wrightwithcaptions.mov" type="video/mp4" autostart="false" 
    height="430" width="540" id="video1" enablejavascript="true" /> 

<a href="javascript:fallback_to_mp4('video1');">
    Mp4 version
</a>
```

Or with this you could listen for error events and change the source to mp4 accordingly:

```
<embed src="wrightwithcaptions.mov" type="video/mp4" autostart="false" 
    height="430" width="540" id="video1" enablejavascript="true" 
    postdomevents="true" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fallback_to_mp4(video) {
        var mov_url = video.GetURL();
        var newsrc = mov_url.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mp4";
        video.SetURL(newsrc);
    }
    var video = document.getElementById("video1");
    video.addEventListener('qt_error', function() {
        fallback_to_mp4(video);
    };
</script>
```

I can't test the solutions now, because I'm on Linux (no quicktime, thanks apple). Anyway, here's the reference document for scripting with QuickTime: [HTML Scripting Guide for QuickTime](http://genekc07.stowers.org/Users/mec/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-QuickTimeandJavaScript).

Comment: My only concern is for accessibility. Some users may have javascript turned off and therefore these won't work. Nevertheless, these are great answers. I really appreciate your feedback. I tried them out and they do work really well.

Comment: Well, QuickTIme doesn't provide fallback videos like HTML5 so unless your faculty changes its mind your only solution is to give the students two pages for the same resource. Redundant, but it'd work. By the way, I find that the use of a proprietary plugin like quicktime is worse for accessibility than using javascript... just my 2¢.

Comment: Another thing. StackOverflow is a community in which the *special* way to say "thanks" is upvoting the answer or accepting it :)